# How to make a custom dropdown that brings up a list from the bottom of the View in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, modal-dialog, dropdown

I need to create a custom dropdown which will bring up a list from the bottom... Does anyone have an idea.

For Example when I press here

[image]

There is a list like HalfModal shows up from the bottom.

Comment: here's a good article that may help https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/12/11/building-bottom-sheet-in-swiftui/

Comment: I ll look into it Thank you!